# How to deeplink from tab bar swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

So I have an app that takes in a deeplink parameter and then what should happen is that deeplink parameter should go to a specific view controller. I'm not getting to that view controller for some reason. So here's the design of the app (--> tab bar controller --> navigation controller --> dashboard VC --> segue to --> notification VC) So basically once I get to the dashboard VC I want to segue to notification VC all from the app delegate.

```
            var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
            rootViewController.selectedIndex = 0
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! MainViewController
            controller.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showChat", sender: controller)
```

The result of this is the tab bar going to where the navigation bar is but nothing is happening after that. I'm really confused and it would be a big help to show what i'm doing wrong. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at coordinator pattern. https://github.com/AndreyPanov/ApplicationCoordinator You can google for more materials related to this. Also, there are other ways, such as using NSNotificationCenter, but coordinator pattern is trending approach and is safer and maintainable for a long term.

**ADDED:**

To open any VC's using storyboard, we need to configure segue from source vc to destination vc in storyboard file. So, you have some options, excluding some hacky techniques, 1) At every storyboard that needs to open that notification VC, configure the segue in storyboard. 2) Don't use storyboard. Use [UIViewController.present(_:animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) to present the notification view controller.

It sounds like the notification VC is a common view controller may show up at any given point of time. If that's truly the case, you can have only the root view controller to open the notification VC. It will appear on top of every other content and modal view controllers.

Comment: I mean I seem to understand how to get to the right controller but I don't know the right code to do it.